# Using Django admin as a base for backend

Tags: python, asp.net-mvc, django, django-admin

First sorry for my poor English.

I came from asp.net mvc. Now I use django with nanoboxio

In asp, I can create sections like below.

1. Create model and add it to dbcontext
2. Right click controller folder and create new controller with views.
3. Modify as you wish

For now, I know Django can create admin interface for your model. I try and happy with it. but i want to develop it.

I want to for example;

1. Create a post model.
2. Create a admin interface for it.
3. Copy generated admin interface controller and views to another app
4. Modify it

How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try at your own first. If you have problems with your code, we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Django's MVC is quite different to ASP. 
Django's MVC pattern is less strict so you sort of combine the view and the controller in the views.py. However, if you want to change the Admin, the Django docs are quite nice here: [docs.djangoproject.com](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/)

If you want to create a custom admin functionality the docs should give you a first idea and if you're planning to create a blog, I would advice you to use an existing plugin such as [Zinnia](https://django-blog-zinnia.com). There, you can find the desired functionalities and modify them instead of building them from scratch.

Also, there are a couple of tutorials on how to build reusable apps and they usually include a detailed guideline how to implement admin functionalities there. Just look it up on google.

I hope that helps you!